# java regex expression, everything other than letter characters/strings

Tags: java, regex, hash, hashtable

I'm writing a hashTable program. I only need to hash values that are either words, or single characters. I will define a word as anything that doesn't have a space or punctuation, and a character is any letter (a-z) or (0-9). This means no spaces, newlines, indents, etc. I have all the text that's being hashed as lower case as well. I'm using the string.split method, although what would be the proper regex expression? I've read a handful of sites and still am confused. 
-Thanks

Comment: Can you provide examples of your data and what you have attempted?

Comment: I want "bensherms!bensherms? bensherms:bensherms
" to return the array: [bensherms,bensherms,bensherms,bensherms]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following as it seems you are trying to accomplish this.

```
String s = "bensherms_!' bensherms?_ bensherms;$#!bensherms";
String[] parts = s.split("(?<!\\W)[\\W_]+");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(parts));
```

See [`live demo`](http://ideone.com/g9K2ie)

Output

```
[bensherms, bensherms, bensherms, bensherms]
```

Regular expression:

```
(?<!           look behind to see if there is not:
 \W            any character of: non-word characters
               (all but a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _)
)              end of look-behind
[\W_]+         any character of: non-word characters 
               (all but a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _), '_' (1 or more times)
```

Comment: Now looking over, how could I use _ as a delimeter?

Comment: Give me an example of your data.

Answer (score 1):

The Pattern API contains a number of useful [predefined character classes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/pre_char_classes.html), which offer convenient shorthands for commonly used regular expressions: For this case `\\w` represents A word character: `[a-zA-Z_0-9]` and `\\s` represents  A white space character: `[ \t\n\x0B\f\r]`. You are probably after them.

**For example**, to split around the white space you will need to use `\\s+` where an expression `X+` says that `X` occurs at least once or more. Such expression is known as [quantifiers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/quant.html).

Comment: What are white space characters?